# Comparing arrays in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, array, comparison

I want to compare two arrays and if they match exactly a specific value should be assigned to a field. For instance, if the values in `"sumEHZ"` are `[A,B]` or `[B,C]` the lower value should be assigned. If `[A,C]` then the value `B` is assigned. (A = good, C is bad).

```sql
CASE

    WHEN array_all(array_distinct(string_to_array("sumEHZ")), array('A','A')) THEN 'A'
    WHEN array_all(array_distinct(string_to_array("sumEHZ")), array('A','B')) THEN 'B'
    WHEN array_all(array_distinct(string_to_array("sumEHZ")), array('B','B')) THEN 'B'
    WHEN array_all(array_distinct(string_to_array("sumEHZ")), array('B','C')) THEN 'C'
    WHEN array_all(array_distinct(string_to_array("sumEHZ")), array('C','A')) THEN 'B'
    WHEN array_all(array_distinct(string_to_array("sumEHZ")), array('C','C')) THEN 'C'

END
```

However, something seems to be wrong. For example for the case `[A,C]` (line 6) I always get `A`, but `B` would be right. If I ran only line 6, I get the right value. I could not find what I'm doing wrong...

Here is a screenshot of the relevant part of the attribute table:
`"IND_1"` and `"IND_2"` is combined in `"sumEHZ"`. `"EHZ"` should be attributed in terms of the rules..

[image]

Comment: As there are only two types `[A,B]`, `[A,C]`, etc., `array_distinct()` is maybe not necessary??

Comment: `array_distinct()` may not be necessary, but removing it alone will not fix the issue,

Answer (score 4):

You need to switch the order of your two arrays within `array_all()`, like this:

```sql
with_variable('myarray','A,C',

CASE

WHEN array_all(array('A','A'),array_distinct(string_to_array(@myarray))) THEN 'A'
WHEN array_all(array('A','B'),array_distinct(string_to_array(@myarray))) THEN 'B'
WHEN array_all(array('B','B'),array_distinct(string_to_array(@myarray))) THEN 'B'
WHEN array_all(array('B','C'),array_distinct(string_to_array(@myarray))) THEN 'C'
WHEN array_all(array('C','A'),array_distinct(string_to_array(@myarray))) THEN 'B'
WHEN array_all(array('C','C'),array_distinct(string_to_array(@myarray))) THEN 'C'

END

)
```

Its documented differently (at least in 3.22.1) (*`"Returns true if an array contains all the values of a given array."`*), but **it seems like the docs should actually state**, that *`array_all(array_a,array_b) returns true if array_a contains all the values of array_b`*.

Answer (score 3):

Re-order your script to bring conditions with duplicated elements ('A's, 'B's, 'C's) down, so that they will not affect other combinations while being evaluated.

**Revised script**

```
CASE

WHEN array_all(array_distinct(string_to_array("sumEHZ")), array('A','B')) THEN 'B'
WHEN array_all(array_distinct(string_to_array("sumEHZ")), array('C','A')) THEN 'B'
WHEN array_all(array_distinct(string_to_array("sumEHZ")), array('B','C')) THEN 'C'
WHEN array_all(array_distinct(string_to_array("sumEHZ")), array('A','A')) THEN 'A'
WHEN array_all(array_distinct(string_to_array("sumEHZ")), array('B','B')) THEN 'B'
WHEN array_all(array_distinct(string_to_array("sumEHZ")), array('C','C')) THEN 'C'

END
```

[image]

**What happened?**

- `array_all(first array, second array)` determines if all the elements in the second array are included in the first array.
- hense, `array_all()` does not distinguish `array('A','A')` from `array('A')` in the second array, because they both provides the same element `'A'`. (Treated as if distinctive values, in a sense).
- your first condition `WHEN array_all(array_distinct(string_to_array("sumEHZ")), array('A','A')) THEN 'A'` asks if one or more `'A'` is (are) included in  your input array.
- so your first condition responds to all inputs with 'A' (['A','A'], ['A','B'],['A','C']) and returns `'A'`.
- you may notice single-array 'A' (`array('A')`) in the posted picture of Expression window. It works the same as (`array('A','A')`).

**Output**

[image]